# How to create an entry without reference id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models like

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_one :handle
end

class Handle < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :car
end
```

(This might not be really accurate since I made up the example now.)

Car model has 'name' string attribute which is unique.

When creating a handle, I would like to do something like

```
Handle.create( { size: 20, car: "CarName"} )
```

So the point is that `car` is not the id of the car but the name.
I know that I just can do like

```
Handle.create( { size: 20, car: Car.find_by_name("CarName") } )
```

but I want to know if I can do it by the first example (by modifying the models somehow)

UPDATE: To make it clear, the actual handle entry I want to create is { size: 20, car : **[car id]** }. So the DB should have Car's id as reference. What I want to do is create such entry by specifying the name which can identify its id.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. Consider If your `car name` changes you will have to change car name in all records of `Handle`

Comment: When I create handle object, it actually uses car's id to reference. I just want to use its name when creating. So it is no problem. Of course when you add something by name, they must know which name to use but it is ok for now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's a good idea — it's overriding the default Rails behavior and hides some of the complexity somewhere underneath, where it is more difficult to refactor.

That being said, one way to do this is to override the `create` class method in the `Handle` class.

```
class Handle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car

  def create(params={})
    if params[:car_name]
      car_name = params.delete(:car_name)
      params.merge(car: Car.find_by(name: car_name))
    end
    super(params)
  end
end
```

That should allow you to call `create` by passing a `car_name`, like this:

```
Handle.create(size: 20, car_name: "Some Car Name")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want it but here is a way to do it.

You can have an `attr_accessor` named `car_name` in `Handle` class. You can set it when initializing the `Handle` object. Then add a `before_validation` and set the corresponding ID.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_one :handle
end

class Handle < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :car
    attr_accessor :car_name
    before_validation :set_car_id_from_name


    private 
    def set_car_id_from_name
     self.car_id = Car.find_by(name: car_name).try(:id) if self.car_id.blank?
     self.car_id
    end
end
```

Now you can create `Handle` by

```
Handle.create(size: 20, car_name: "Some Car Name")
```

Please note if you set `car_id` explicitly then It wont change it. i-e

```
Handle.create(size: 20,car: Car.first)
```

In this case it will create a handle for the `first` car. So you can ow have both way to create `handle`